# NSString nslog revealing "\n" newline character

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsstring, newline

I want to log an NSString but when I log it, it doesn't show the new line character "
n". How can I make it so it does? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can process the string first and replace all occurrences of `\n` with `\\n`

```
NSString *newString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
```

Comment: Parameters are reversed. I had to use [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"]