# Objective c Custom Object Description Issue

Tags: ios, logging, nsstring, formatting, custom-object

I have some trouble logging custom objects.

An Example with a DateObject Class:

Header

```
@interface DateObject : NSObject {

    NSString *month;
    NSString *day;
    NSString *year;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *month;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *day;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *year;
- (NSString *)description;
```

Implementation:

```
#import "DateObject.h"

@implementation DateObject
@synthesize month, day, year;

- (NSString *)description{
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n\tMonth:\t%@\n\tDay:\t%@\n\tYear:\t%@\n}",self.month, self.day, self.year];
    return result;
}

@end
```

Now I set the Values like this:

```
DateObject *date = [[[DateObject alloc] init] autorelease];
date.month       = @"Mar";
date.day         = @"04";
date.year        = @"2013";
```

Logging the Object with this

```
NSLog(@"{\n\tMonth:\t%@\n\tDay:\t%@\n\tYear:\t%@\n}",date.month, date.day, date.year);
```

results (as expected) in

```
2013-03-04 10:42:08.821 LoggingCustomObjectsExample[4389:c07] {
    Month:  Mar
    Day:    04
    Year:   2013
}
```

Now trying to log the object with

```
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

I expect my `description` method to get called (it actually does get called), but the result always is unformatted:

```
2013-03-04 10:59:18.835 LoggingCustomObjectsExample[4389:c07] DateObject: "{\n\tMonth:\tMar\n\tDay:\t04\n\tYear:2013}";
```

I dont understand why the escape sequences are not working here.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This is known behaviour of `NSLog` and it's escaping those newline and tab characters so the output remains on a single line (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052073/nsstring-nslog-revealing-n-newline-character)).

I would say that you don't want newline characters in your `description` output anyway, as they add no value.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I did not know this was a known behaviour. I just thought it would have been nice to have a formatted log like logging an NSArray

Comment: You probably still can, just not using `NSLog()`.  (I don't use `NSLog()` in production code anyway, and rely on my own logging code).

Comment: May I ask why you dont use NSLog()? I have been using NSLog() all the time... Is this bad in any way?

Comment: I don't use `NSLog()` because I write my logging data to file, so I can optionally upload them somewhere or get the user to send them to me for post-mortem debugging.  My logging code also provides logging levels with runtime support to turn off verbose debug-level messages, which are generally only useful to me during development.